# Alternating Richfaces DataTable Row Color

Tags: css, richfaces

What is the easiest way to alternate a row color using RichFaces dataTable component?

Comment: you need to accept answers to your questions with the checkmark under each number of votes. You should even accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the rowClasses attribute of the  component.

Sorry.. figured this out in two seconds reading the richfaces documentation.

:)

Comment: Link for extendedDataTable: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/extendedDataTable.jsf?tab=info